# Change ng-model through directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-controller

I'am trying to change ng-model of input inside directive by clicking on Edit anchor in directives template.

Function f() is suppose to access outer controller and bind the editableValue to name or company so i can change it through input.

Input does show persons values but it does not bind to it.

```
<p edit="person.name"></p>
<p edit="person.company"></p> 
<input ng-model="editableValue">

main.controller('editsCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.setToEdit = function(val){
        $scope.editableValue = val;
    }
}); 

main.directive('edit', function(){
return{
    template:'{{edit}}<a ng-click="f()"> Edit </a>',
    restrict:'A',
    scope:{
        edit:"="
    },
    replace:false,

    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
            scope.f = function(){
                  scope.$parent.setToEdit(scope.edit);
            }
          } 
    }
})
```

Even if i do this, its not binded, just value is passed:

```
scope.$parent.editableValue = scope.$parent.person.name;
```

For newbie this becomes bit confusing, what am i missing?

Answer (score 0):

Scope assignment is failing here:

```
scope.f = function(){
                  scope.$parent.setToEdit(scope.edit);
            }
```

Because you limited scope here:

```
scope:{
        edit:"="
    },
```

Edit is the only scope parent will see because you have set two way databinding on it with '='

Comment: Ty, that isnt only problem, and it really doesnt have to be binded like that, if i could do something like ng-model="editableValue['someproperty']" and set $scope.someproperty depending on link attr value ( after dot ofcourse ) or similliar, it would work excellent. Did try many variations like "currentPerson['{{someproperty}}']", and did experiment with $parse inside directive ...